# Saving chosen row data from tableview in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am having table view in my iPhone application. The requirement is that I have to use gestures for that table view so that when user tap+hold on a row then a dialogue box should come up confirming user to save the data of that specific row to iPhone core data or nsuserdefaults.

I want to know that what option would be the best to save the data i.e., core data or nsuserdefaults?

And the most important How can I achieve it?

I need any example or code snippet to get accomplish this...

thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for NSUserDefault if I am sure that will be no more than 10-20 rows of data, otherwise I would go for CoreData so it can be scaled in the future. I would use the LongPressGestureRecognizer in the cell to get the indexPath of the cell and display the dialog  as shown in sample code below.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        UILongPressGestureRecognizer *pressRecongnizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tableCellPressed:)];
            pressRecongnizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.5f;
            [cell addGestureRecognizer:pressRecongnizer];
            [pressRecongnizer release];
    }
    // your cell info
    cell.textLabel.text = @"test";
    return cell;
} 

- (void)tableCellPressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    // You can access to the tableview cell from the recognizer.view
    // You can get the data directly from the cell data more or label and etc.
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)recognizer.view;

    // You can either get the NSIndexPath of the cell from the tableview to 
    // access the data model from you data collection.
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableview indexPathForCell:cell]

    // Use the index path to get data and display dialog.
    // For example:
    UIAlertView *alert = [UIAlertView alloc] – initWithTitle:@"table cell pressed" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion

Small amounts of data: NSUserDefaults

Moderate amounts: plists

Large amounts: CoreData,sqlite

First, let’s take a look at using SQLite directly.

- Relational Database System
- Potential for cross platform compatibility
- Many early iPhone database examples were written using SQLite
- Objective-C wrappers such as FMDB are pretty easy to use

Now at Core Data:

- Can store data in it’s own Binary, or SQLite storage format.
- Can serialize objects
- Much higher level than using SQLite directly
- Not a RDBMS you could actually just store things directly.

Now the real question is, which is easier to use?  Well, that really depends on what you’re doing.  In an app I recently created all I had to do was read small amounts of data sequentially from a SQLite database, since this is such a simple task I simply used FMDB along with iPhone SQLite.  Now, if I needed to do anything with the data beyond reading it, Core Data can make all this much easier, and I’d recommend using it.

Conclusion: Core Data just makes so many things so much easier that I would recommend using it unless you already have existing code, or are doing only the most basic database usage

here is a list of some tutorials

1. http://www.applausible.com/blog/?p=317
2. http://maniacdev.com/2010/04/great-beginners-core-data-tutorial/
3. http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/nsuserdefaults_iphone-sdk/

Answer (score 0):

I think if we're talking about really a lot of date, you would better use core data. If you only neet to store very little information, such as user settings or something like that `NSUserDefaults` is the right way to go.

How to achieve that:
You ne a NSTimer as aproperty, i just called it `yourTimer`
In your ViewController with the tableView you will need to implement the following methods:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [yourTimer invalidate];
    yourTimer = nil;
}
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
     [yourTimer invalidate];
     yourTimer = nil;
}
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint *currentPosition = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    //here you have to check if the touch is inside the cell you wanted
    //note that this code wont work, you have to personalize it, this is only a hint
    if ([currentPosition isInsideYourCell]){
        if (!yourTimer.isValid) {
            // NSLog(@"testausgabe");
            yourTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 //any interval you like 
                                                         target:self 
                                                       selector:@selector(onTick:) 
                                                       userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
           [yourTimer fire];
         }
     }

}
- (BOOL)isInsideYourCell{
//check if the touch is inside the cell
}
- (void)onTick:(NSTimer *)timer {
    if (timer.timeInterval >= 2.0){
        //lets say your dialogue will appear after 2 secconds
        [self displayYourDialogue];
    }
}
```

I hope you get it with this help.